# How to execute windows batch command from sql?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, batch-processing

HI
I have written a windows batch command that operates on video files which are stored on a oracle database. What is best way to execute this batch command on those video files ?
One way I can think of is to pull the video files to temporary folder using a sql script and write another program, maybe in java, to execute the batch command on those files and store the result in separate folder or commit in database.

Appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [DBMS_SCHEDULER](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10739/scheduse.htm#i1021522) to run external (executable) jobs.
An example [here](http://dbaspot.com/oracle-server/65458-help-getting-executable-run-under-dbms_scheduler.html)

Not sure how your batch file 'gets' the video files from Oracle. I'd look as BFILEs as one option.

Comment: Gary the 2nd link times out for me. Thanks for the response.